# How can I display two Objects (Book and Feed_modell ) in a List of Objects without get duplicated data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase Database is being accessed twice, once for Feed_modell and another for Book and showing duplicate data, how can I fetch Firebase data from different models (Book and Feed_modell) one time in a List.

I tried to fetch data from the Feed_modell model and then the Book template, but my Firebase fetch the 4 data into the Feed_modell and then again the same four data into the Book.

```
private RecyclerViewFeedAdapter Adapter;
private List<Object> feedList;

private void loadtheFeed() {

    feedList.clear();

    dbs = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("feedPosts");
    Query query = dbs.child(feedReceivingKey);
    childEventListener1 = query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Feed_modell post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Feed_modell.class);
            Book book = dataSnapshot.getValue(Book.class);

            feedList.add(post);
            feedList.add(book);

            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled( DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Read my Firebase once for both models.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What about the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Yes Sir. The code makes my Database read twice what causes my data to be duplicated, I think it's because of adding two different objects separately in the same List of Objects, i mean: feedList.add (Feed_modell) feedList.add (Book ); could be the reason for the problem. How could you solve this problem

Comment: You're only attaching a single listener with `query.addChildEventListener(...`, so that should be the only listener that is being added from this code. The `onChildAdded` of that listener will be called for each child matching the query.

Comment: But you're reading two objects from each child node `ataSnapshot.getValue(Feed_modell.class);` and `dataSnapshot.getValue(Book.class);`. Since you add both to your `feedList`, you're adding two objects for each child node. If you only want one object for each child node, you should only call `feedList.add(...)` once per child node, with the object you want to add.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes sir, but the problem is that my database reads twice every child node. It shows the first 4 child nodes and then reads the 4 child nodes. That makes me confused.